# Converting a method argument into an enum

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I have an enum type defined like so:

```
public enum Status
{
    Active=1,
    InActive=0
}
```

in my method can I cast the parameter into the enum like this:

```
public string doSomething(string param1, int status)
{
//will this work?      
Account.Status = (Status) status;
//or do i need to test one by one like this
if(status == 0)
{
 Account.Status = Status.Inactive;
 //and so on...
} // end if
}  // end doSomething
```

Comment: Why not just run the code and find out.

Comment: @Kaf Possible reason: he's using a database that supports `int`, but not `enum`.

Comment: Yes, it will work. However, It's best to check if int is in the range of declared enum first.

Comment: i ran the code...the compiler didnt complain.what happens when a value thats not in the enum is passed in?

Comment: @MichaelCwienczek ok so i can just do a check for the range first as opposed to doing multiple ifs?

Comment: @sirbombay you should be able to try that yourself quite easy...

Comment: because its inside a web service and...no excuse i'll find out myself.thanks everyone including those who angrily downvoted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the int is a valid value for Status and then do a conversion.

```
public string doSomething(string param1, int status)
{
    if (IsValidEnum<Status>(status))
    {
        Account.Status = (Status)status;
    }
    ...
}

private bool IsValidEnum<T>(int value)
{
    var validValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
    var validIntValues = validValues.Cast<int>();
    return validIntValues.Any(v => v == value);
}
```

In de else of the if you can throw an exception if you wish.

Comment: i guess this is the magic i was looking for...thanks

Comment: `Enum.IsDefined` already does this - see my answer.

Comment: @James, Ok, it was fun to create the method but unneseccary...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do a straight cast from `int` to `enum` (given that an `enum` representation of that integer exists).

If you need to check whether the `enum` exists before parsing use [Enum.IsDefined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx) i.e.

```
if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Status), status))
{
    Account.Status = (Status)status;
}
```

Comment: what happens when it doesnt exist?

Comment: The variable being assigned reverts to `int` - both types are interchangeable so you won't get an exception.

Answer (score 1):

well of course you can do that. just try and see.

you can also cast the other way

```
(int)Account.Status
```

it's possible to cast Enum to int and vice versa, because every Enum is actually represented by an int per default. You should manually specify member values. By default it starts from 0 to N.

if you try to convert an enum value that does not exist it'll work, but wont give you an enum value if you try to compare it the any value you have in the enum

Comment: I actually tried it..it compiled fine.but my worry is what happens when a value is passed in that doesnt exist in the enum?

Comment: @sirbombay You can try that 2 :)

Comment: @sirbombay read my edited answer

Comment: it now makes sense...i guess i shd find that out myself too :)